# Prove $4^k - 1$ is divisible by $3$ for $k = 1, 2, 3, \dots$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

For example:

$$\begin{align}
4^{1} - 1 \mod 3 &=
\\
4 -1 \mod 3 &= 
\\
3 \mod 3 &=
\\3*1 \mod 3 &=0
\\
\\
4^{2} - 1 \mod 3 &=
\\
16 -1 \mod 3 &= 
\\
15 \mod 3 &=
\\3*5 \mod 3 &= 0
\\
\\
4^{3} - 1 \mod 3 &=
\\
64 -1 \mod 3 &= 
\\
21 \mod 3 &=
\\3*7 \mod 3 &=
 0\end{align}
$$

Define $x = \frac{4^k - 1}{3}$. So far I have:

$$k_1 \to 1 \Longrightarrow x_1 \to 1
\\
k_2 \to 2 \Longrightarrow x_2 \to 5
\\
k_3 \to 3 \Longrightarrow x_3 \to 21
\\
k_4 \to 4 \Longrightarrow x_4 \to 85$$

But then it's evident that

$$4^{k_n} = x_{n+1} - x_n$$

I don't know if this helps, these are ideas floating in my head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we know that $$4\equiv 1 \mod 3$$ and thus $$4^k\equiv 1^k\equiv 1 \mod 3$$

Comment: So is it true then that $a*b \mod m = (a \mod m)(b \mod m)$?

Comment: @DonLarynx Not really, but $(a*b)\pmod{m}\equiv (a\pmod{m}*b\pmod{m})\pmod{m}$. Your claim wouldn't always work, conder $a=2$, $b=5$, $m=7$

Answer (score 7):

You may also go about this easily with induction:

$$4^{n+1}-1 = (3+1)\cdot 4^n-1 = 3\cdot 4^n + (4^{n}-1)$$

Comment: touche, touche.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$4 \equiv 1 \mod 3 \Rightarrow 4^n \equiv 1^n \mod 3 \Rightarrow 4^n \equiv 1 \mod 3$$

Answer (score 3):

$4^k-1=(4-1)(4^{k-1}+\cdots+4+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

4 is congruent to 1 modulo 3, so:

$$4^k - 1 \equiv 1^k - 1 \equiv 0 \mod{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another possible proof: Expand $4^k - 1 = (3 + 1)^k - 1$ using the
[Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Use the remainder theorem in the following form :

$$4^k-1=(3+1)^k-1=3L+1^k-1=3L$$

where $L$ is an integer.

Hint:Expand $(3+1)^k$ using the binomial expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^k - y^k$ is always divisible by $x-y$. (In fact, $x^k - y^k = (x - y)(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2}y + x^{k-3}y^2 + \cdots + y^{k-1})$ Specialize for $x=4, y=1$.